# How to derive the distribution of a Random variable which is a function of Normal

Tags: normal-distribution, truncated-normal-distribution

I am interested to know the distribution of following expression -

```
X ~ N(0, 200)
Y = min(X + c, 0), c > 0
```

I thought `Y` should follow some `Truncated Normal distribution` with `mean`c`, and sd = 200`. So I compared the mean value directly from random numbers generated from `Y` and from corresponding `Truncated Normal distribution` as below -

#### Explicitly get values of `Y`

```
Const = 50
Value = rnorm(100000, 0, 200)
Value1 = sapply(Value, function(x) min(x + Const, 0))
Mean_Value1 = mean(Value1)
Mean_Value1
#-57.14933
```

#### From Truncated Normal -

```
library(truncnorm)
Value2 = rtruncnorm(n = 100000, a = -Inf, b = 0, mean = Const, sd = 200)
Mean_Value2 = mean(Value2)
Mean_Value2
# -142.8507
```

Based on above result, apparently `Y` doesnt follow Truncated Normal. Can somebody help me to derive the right distribution of `Y`? My ultimate goal is to derive the `CDF of Y`.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\Phi$ be the cdf of the standard normal distribution. Then $X \sim \Phi\left(\frac{\cdot}{\sqrt{200}}\right)$. The cdf of $Y$ is by definition:

- If $y<0$: $\mathbb{P}[Y\leq y]=\Phi\left(\frac{y - c}{\sqrt{200}}\right)$
- If $y\geq0$: $\mathbb{P}[Y\leq y]= 1$

So you can express it as $\mathbb{P}[Y\leq y]=\Phi\left(\frac{\min(y, 0) - c}{\sqrt{200}}\right)+ (1-\Phi\left(\frac{-c}{\sqrt{200}}\right))\mathbb{I}_{y\geq 0}$

where $\mathbb{I}$ is the indicator function (1 if predicate is true, 0 otherwise).

Comment: Many thanks. Is there any way to find to solve for y where the Probability = (say) 40% or can we approximate above probability function?

Comment: The cdf of the Gaussian is the well-known error function (erf). Solving for y has no closed form solution. However, erf is well studied and you can usually check tables (you have some in Wikipedia) or use some oracle functions (e.g. scipy.special.erf in Python). Note that you will have to consider your discontinuity: If the cdf at (-c / sqrt(200)) has a value less than your 0.4, then your y=0.